# How to reinitialize jQuery unobtrusive validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am loading a form with the proper attributes for jQuery via an AJAX call, the problem is because it's being loaded in after the document is ready the jQuery unobtrusive validation is not picking up the required validation. Can anyone tell me the method I would run to reinitialize it?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to *try* to initialize it?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm trying to see if there's a reinit function but it seems that once it has been set up with .validate, it cannot really be unbound and you're stuck with the original settings... :/

Comment: @MykaEyl Just reinitialize it in the complete or success method like below.

Comment: Oh ok... I missread the post, I wanted to change the validate settings after it has been set once (because in the JS file we can see that it always reloads the initial validator object, even when we supply new options) which is a different problem.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To parse the form's validation attributes after you return it to the page you need to run this: `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#yourFormSelector')`

In my application I put this call into the ajaxComplete handler so I don't have to worry about it anymore. I have it reparse every form on the page and it's been working fine in production for quite a while (even when there are a couple hundred forms on the page).

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize it within the success callback of whichever ajax method you are using, using the same call you are currently using to initialize the validation

```
  $(selector).load( formUrl, function(){

    /* form exists here, run code*/
  })
```